# Creating a file pointer causes an Exception in Android Development

Tags: android

Hello StackOverFlow Community. This is my first time posting, so I apologize if I have made any mistakes!

I have been attempting to obtain the app's internal storage directory for reading and writing files.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class Security_Management extends ActionBarActivity

....Other Functions...

public byte[] Encrypted_File_Reader (String File_Name) throws Exception
{
    /* Checks that the File can be Created/Exists **/
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), File_Name);
    if(file.exists() == false)
    {
        byte[] Output = null;
        return Output;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Prepares to Read the File **/
        InputStream Input = new FileInputStream(file);

        /* Prepares to Read in the Data **/
        ByteArrayOutputStream contents = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        /* Reads the File **/ 
        do 
        {
            len = Input.read(data);

            if (len > 0) contents.write(data, 0, len);

        } while (len == data.length);

        byte[] Draft_Byte_Output = contents.toByteArray();

        /* Decodes the File **/
        byte[] Output = Decoder(User_Key, Draft_Byte_Output);

        /* Finishes **/
        Input.close();

        return Output;
    }
}
```

However, every single time I attempt to run the code, an exception occurs on the following line:

```
File file = new File(CtWr.getFilesDir(), File_Name);
```

I'm at a loss as to what is causing the exception, as my app relies on this function for it to work. Thank you for any replies!!

*Addition*
I think this is the stack trace:

```
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826):     at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
08-12 00:18:34.756: W/Binder(5826):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been attempting to use the ContextWrapper in my app in order to obtain the app's internal storage directory for reading and writing files.

You do not need to create a `ContextWrapper` "in order to obtain the app's internal storage directory for reading and writing files". For starters, `Activity` *is* a `ContextWrapper`.

> However, every single time I attempt to run the code, an exception occurs on the following line:

Get rid of `CtWr.` and call `getFilesDir()` on the activity itself.

In the future, if you are crashing, [use LogCat to examine your Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would you be able to provide an example code for calling "getFilesDir() on the activity itself". I apologize as I'm quite new to app development!

Comment: @AlexStonard: "I apologize as I'm quite new to app development!" -- more importantly, you are quite new to Java. I strongly encourage you to put Android aside for a while and learn Java. With respect to this change, simply delete the five characters `CtWr.` before `getFilesDir()`, then save your changes to the file (e.g., `<Ctrl>-<S>`).

Comment: I have followed your advice (changed the line to "File file = new File(getFilesDir(), File_Name)", but it still throws an exception. With regards to your comment about learning java, I have gone through the basics. However, due to college, I have had to fast-track this so that I am able to perform a number of basic tasks in android before terms starts.

Comment: @AlexStonard: "but it still throws an exception" -- then I suggest clicking on the link in my answer and learning how to review the Java stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: Ok, I have looked at the stack trace, but I am confused by the NPE! It shouldn't occur as I am initialising the file object, not using it!

Comment: @AlexStonard: That is not a stack trace from your app.

Comment: Oh how embarrassing for me!! Sorry, I think I found it now! Im so sorry you have to put up with someone like me!

Comment: @AlexStonard: That is not a stack trace at all. The previous one you had was a stack trace, just not from your app. Note that if you are using Eclipse, and you have been catching this exception in a debugger, you need to run past the point of the exception, so the stack trace gets logged to LogCat.

Comment: Ok, I think this is definitely it!!

Comment: @AlexStonard: That says that you are crashing at line 397 of `Longer_Tasks.java`, in your `Profile_Load_Data_From_File()` method, where you are passing `null` as the second parameter to `Log.e()`.